# Full-screen <video>: what kind of CSS magic is this?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

This [example](http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video) demonstrates how to create a full-screen HTML5 video. It uses the following CSS code:

```
video#bgvid { 
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
   z-index: -100;
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
   background-size: cover; 
}
```

I am wondering what is the meaning behind all these properties. I understand why one uses a `fixed` position and `z-index` for putting it all behind. What I can't understand is this:

- Why `{ width: 100%; height: 100% }` doesn't work properly but a combination of `{ width: auto; min-width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 100% }` does.
- Why first set `top` and `left` to 50% and then `translate` back using `transform`s?
- How to adapt this to be not 100% of the viewport, but 100% of the parent element (e.g. a `<section>`)?

Comment: The second point is a trick that is generally used for horizontal and vertical centering of the element. For example, setting `left: 50%` positions the left edge of the element at the center and then `translateX(-50%)` moves the left edge further to the left by half the width of that element. First point should basically be to allow the element to extend beyond 100% if needed.

Comment: Harry, thanks a lot! You should add this as an answer, not as a comment – I'd accept it!

Comment: I hadn't added it as an answer because I didn't answer all your questions and wasn't sure about the need for the setting in Point 1 (though I could understand what it was doing). Alvaro's answer covers it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `{ width: 100%; height: 100% }` doesn't work properly but a combination of `{ width: auto; min-width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 100% }` does.

This is probably easier to explain if you consider the HTML5 video as a two part thing: on one hand you have the container (the `<video>`) and on the other hand you have the movie (specified in the `<source>` or the `src`).

When you set up a `width` and `height`, what you are doing is setting up the `width` and `height` of the container and not the movie itself. The movie will grow/shrink preserving its aspect ratio until it hits 100% of the width or the height of the container.

With that in mind, let's see both cases separately:

- When you set the `width` and `height` to 100%, you are setting the container to a specific value: occupy the full size of the screen. Then the movie will adjust its size to the size of the container as explained above, and that's what causes the "black bars" on top/bottom (or left/right for vertical videos).

  In this case, "the movie would adapt to the container size".

  One possibility to fix this, would be to programmatically tell the movie to fit the container using the CSS rule: `object-fit:cover`. That works in a similar way to how `background-size:cover` works with images, but it may not be the best option as [`object-fit` is not fully supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit).
- When you set `width` and `height` to `auto`, and `min-width` and `min-height` to 100%, you are just giving a *guideline* to the container: it must have at least the height and width of the screen (but it could have more). The movie will be able to grow proportionally to its aspect ratio without containing restrictions, so its sizes will overflow the one of the window.

  In this case, "the container would adapt to the movie size".

This pictures represent what happens in the cases I tried to explain above, I hope it helps:

[image]

> Why first set `top` and `left` to 50% and then `translate` back using `transforms`?

This is a trick to center the video within the screen. Normally in a movie, the action will be happening around the center rather than in the corners; so you want to have as much of the center as visible as possible.

If you just place the video with `top` and `left` values to 0, and a `width` and `height` (or `min-width` and `min-height`) of 100%, then the video will be attached to the top left corner, and you may miss what's on the right and bottom sides.

By setting the video in the center of the screen and translating it using `transform`, you make sure that the center of the video will be at the center of the screen, and the borders are the ones being left out of view.

[image]

> How to adapt this to be not 100% of the viewport, but 100% of the parent element (e.g. a `<section>`)?

This can be achieved by setting that section to a `relative` position, and the video to an `absolute` position (instead of `fixed`). That way the video will adapt to its parent and not to the window.

A similar question was [asked as a comment by EM](http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video#comment-1488422167) in the tutorial page that you linked. That same user posted his/her own solution (by tweaking the relative/absolute positioning as described) and shared the code in this codepen: http://codepen.io/emmajean/pen/nyhFL.

Comment: Alvaro, brilliant answer. Thanks for your time.